# ECG noise filtering using FIR Bandpass Filter

Tags: matlab, filter-design, noise, bandpass, finite-impulse-response

I am new to signal processing and examine ECG data corrupted with noise. The clean data has a frequency spectrum like this.

[image: Spectrum1]

And the corrupted one looks like  this (sorry for the different scale)
[image: Spectrum2]

I am asked to find a FIR band pass filter in matlab to filter out the noise. Unfortunatly I am using filters for the first time so I played with the coefficients and found something like this (The only thing that seems to be clear to me is that the bandpass has to be between something like 1-30 but I have trouble choosing the other parameters.)

$Fstop1 = 0.01$

$Fpass1 = 3$

$Fpass2 = 25$

$Fstop2 = 60$

$Astop1 = 80$

$Apass = 1$

$Astop2 = 30$

$Fs = 250$

The result is not 100% satisfying (I am still having a lot of baseline fluctuations). Is it possible to get "good" results in doing this? Can anybody see heavy mistakes in my parameters that could lead to problems? Or can anyone tell me better coefficients to use?

Comment: Could you add links to the figures you mention in your question?

Comment: Sure. [link1](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC7uRjL4izCrFIZ7tpVn_CLkdX65DdgPjAD1ptjbtS05g/12/77998751/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/clean_Freq.jpg/CJ_VmCUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/yRNe99XSLlyW8oaZN6iuIQoT2djoouIK8hyyWnbvtCY?size=1280x960&size_mode=2) for the first one and [link2](https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAD87EQ6JHMtgIJWmCUUCxjEda8EcnqMPH4EZXc7IqHAOw/12/77998751/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/corrupted_freq.jpg/CJ_VmCUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/YEH4B1tRPKlCGPFpdHesDs6-4Nvhr1av6eHaEyXSqUw?size=1280x960&size_mode=2) for the second one.

Comment: Can't access those dropbox files: "Error (403)
It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home."

Comment: Sorry, these links should work now: [link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbe1dg3pijbe71l/clean_Freq.jpg?dl=0) and [link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/im0xd6l1od5mcgv/corrupted_freq.jpg?dl=0)